# Why wp-options table is 60GB but backup is 24Mb

Tags: mysql, wordpress

After Deleting Transients. Cleaning autoload Options. Setting log_days in my.cnf to 1, an many more tricks... My wp-options says its size is 50GB... however when I backup the file is 24MB.

I'm clearly missing something that is causing me huge binlog files and space problems on the server.

It as bitnami Wordpress installation on a Lightsail server

Any clues will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Did you `OPTIMIZE TABLE` after deleting transients?

Comment: @BillKarwin I did, using MySQL client and got the message that Table (wp_options) does not support optimize, doing analyze and recreate instead, then an error was thrown "option name rewrite_rules was duplicated"... So I used WP_Optimize and it told me that it was optimize

Comment: The message about not supporting optimize is [normal for InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimize-table.html#optimize-table-innodb-details). I see WP_Optimize allows does run optimize table on your behalf, if you check the boxes to enable that. So after doing that, does the table size look more like what you expect?

Comment: Ok... thanks for letting me know. I did run it again using the mysql client and now it tells me the MySQL/data folder is 6.9GB vs 59.8GB... however wp_optimize and DBeaver info tells me the table is still 59.8GB... OPTIMIZE TABLE keeps saying that operation has failed due to the rewrite_rules duplicated key. Should I repair that first?

Comment: That is not an error familiar to me. It sounds like something specific to Wordpress, so I suggest you ask on https://make.wordpress.org/chat/

Comment: I did, thanks. You know I did a SQL Dump and loaded on a local db, apparently it copied all data but there the table is 8mb and in my original server still on 59gb??

Comment: I guess either some of the tables are still fragmented, or the space is used by logs. You can view [SHOW BINARY LOGS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-binary-logs.html) to view the log files and their sizes. You can use [SHOW TABLE STATUS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-table-status.html) to view the size of each table (data + index + free space).

Comment: It was a binlog file of 850MB that was not getting picked up in the PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE "TODAY" deleted it and it when back to 9mb. Thanks for your help SHOW BINARY LOGS Helped me find out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary of the comment thread above:

A combination of using `OPTIMIZE TABLE` to defragment the InnoDB tables after deleting lots of data, and `PURGE BINARY LOGS` to prune the accumulated binary logs helped to reduce the storage usage.

Comment: Thanks for the summary

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL8, they have turned on binary logging by default and the default purge (expiry/deletion) of binary logs is set to 30days.

Once you are in your SSH and in mysql, you can use the below commands

**To show binary logs**

```
mysql> SHOW BINARY LOGS;
```

**To Purge binary logs manually until some point**

```
mysql> PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'binlog.000142';
```

**Change automatic default purge expiry from 30days (deafault) to 3days**

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL binlog_expire_logs_seconds = (60*60*24*3);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET PERSIST binlog_expire_logs_seconds = (60*60*24*3);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

The above value is in seconds, i.e. 3 days in seconds = (60 seconds x 60 minutes x 24 hours x 3 days)